# Using LCD from tablet

Tags: lcd

I have a broken tablet with a good LCD screen.

The LCD has a 40 pin socket, like this [Original 10.1" LCD screen YDS101 WR02-16 YLMB-01490B-28W-A1](https://s.click.aliexpress.com/e/cZU5QEzG) for the Mediatek k107.

I can't understand, what is that socket? It doesn't look like MIPI, maybe it is DSI or LVDS?

Is it possible to use this LCD with the Pi for experiments with HDMI to LVDS adapters or something else?

Comment: Given the high pin count of the connector, it's most likely parallel 8+8+8 RGB.

Comment: Ok, but how can I figure out pinout of the screen?)

Comment: Looks like a FFC (flex flat cable) connector. From that you can't conclude what type of interface the screen uses. For a start: get the product ID (hopefully on the back of the screen) and search for any datasheets / information online.

Comment: Already tried to Google datasheets for it, but there are no datasheets for that screen :)